# Add dynamically a Fragment on my Activity

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-framelayout

I'm using fragments and when I select something on my left fragment, I want a right fragment to be created by my main activity.

So I did this to add my Fragment on a FrameLayout :

```
//add a fragment
FluxDetailFragment myFragment = new FluxDetailFragment();
fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.frameLayout3, myFragment);
fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

But I get this error :

```
02-02 15:34:03.104: E/AndroidRuntime(14794): java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.
```

Do I have to remove my FrameLayout view before? Or another view? How to do so?

Comment: Can you put FluxDetailFragment's onCreate and onCreateView here?

Comment: Mistake from myself, I used inflate from root instead of "null"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve my problem, I had this :

```
View result = inflater.inflate(R.layout.view2);
```

Instead of that, I did this :

```
View result = inflater.inflate(R.layout.view2, null);
```

attachToRoot must be set to null to work.